# For which finite groups $G$ does the Wedderburn decomposition of $\mathbb{Q}[G]$ consist only of fields and division algebras?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. Then the rational group algebra $\mathbb{Q}[G]$ has a wedderburn decomposition of the form $\prod_i M_{n_i}(D_i)$ where each $D_i$ is a division algebra.

My question is: for which $G$ do we have $n_i=1$ for all $i$? In other words, for which finite groups $G$ does the Wedderburn decomposition of $\mathbb{Q}[G]$ consist only of fields and division algebras?

Clearly, this is true when $G$ is abelian. Another example is $G=Q_8$, the quaternion group of order $8$. Are there other examples? Is there a complete classification of such groups? If so, can you provide a reference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The groups you are looking for are precisely those for which the group algebra $\mathbb Q[G]$ does not contain nonzero nilpotent elements. These groups have been classified by Sehgal in [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01168879). The finite groups which have this property are the abelian ones and the Hamiltonian groups of order $2^mt$ (where $t$ is odd), such that $2$ has odd order modulo $t$.

Comment: Note that Sehgal's paper is freely available [here](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/download/PPN365956996_0015/PPN365956996_0015___LOG_0008.pdf).

Comment: @abx Thanks for the link to freely available version - I was struggling to get hold of a copy before that.

Answer (score 7):

The condition is clearly equivalent to require that the group algebra $\mathbb{Q}G$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements and there is already an answer here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906764/reduced-group-algebras

Answer (score 1):

A classification of finite subgroups of multiplicative groups of division algebras over $\mathbb{Q}$ was given by [Fein and Schacher](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869371900238) (Sect 2. there), building on work by Amitsur.
In particular such a group is either soluble, of a restricted set of types listed there, or $SL(2,5)$.

So the groups $S$ you are after are built off these groups. However, you can prune that list further, by only taking these that are of the type you are after. E.g. $SL(2,5)$ need not be considered, as its quotient $A_5$ is not of your type.